# BigSur Active directory connectivity issues (offline after successful bind.)

Tags: terminal, network, vpn, active-directory, big-sur

I've installed BigSur on physical machine and bind it to remote LDAP server which reside behind vpn server.

The bind itself went just fine, but when I try to login or fetch any of the AD users, it fails and although the LDAP seems bounded, the AD nodes cannot be connected (all are offline)

```
Name                                          State   Refs Type         External Locked Hidden 
--------------------------------------------- ------- ---- ------------ -------- ------ ------ 
/Active Directory                                     2                          X      X      
/Active Directory/MYSERVERDEV                         11                                       
/Active Directory/MYSERVERDEV/All Domains     Offline 2    Virtual node                        
/Active Directory/MYSERVERDEV/Global Catalog          2    Virtual node                 X      
/Active Directory/MYSERVERDEV/myserverdev.com Offline 16   Virtual node                 X      
/Configure                                            1                          X      X      
/Contacts                                     Online  3                                        
/LDAPv3                                               1                          X      X      
/Local                                        Online  2                          X      X      
/Local/Default                                Online  6                          X             
/Search                                       Online  5
```

from the logs I could see that the opendirectoryd keep trying to connect the nodes but they remain offline. I wonder if there's any timeout for the connection or anything else that can effect the connection, since the bind itself did work successfully. any ideas ?

```
[com.apple.opendirectoryd:session] /Active Directory/MYSERVERDEV/All Domains nodestate: 
starting check

[com.apple.opendirectoryd:session] /Active Directory/MYSERVERDEV/All Domains nodestate: 
failed to create connection

[com.apple.opendirectoryd:session] /Active Directory/MYSERVERDEV/All Domains nodestate: 
failed to create connection

opendirectoryd: [com.apple.opendirectoryd:session] /Active Directory/MYSERVERDEV/All Domains 
nodestate: next check in 30 seconds

[com.apple.opendirectoryd:session] /Active Directory/MYSERVERDEV/All Domains 
nodestate: is still offline

[com.apple.opendirectoryd:session] /Active Directory/MYSERVERDEV/myserverdev.com 
nodestate: starting check

[com.apple.opendirectoryd:session] /Active Directory/MYSERVERDEV/myserverdev.com 
service discovery: timed out after 5 seconds

[com.apple.opendirectoryd:session] /Active Directory/MYSERVERDEV/myserverdev.com 
nodestate: next check in 15 seconds

[com.apple.opendirectoryd:session] /Active Directory/MYSERVERDEV/myserverdev.com 
nodestate: is still offline
```

Comment: As Big Sur is still in beta (and I assume you are on the *public* beta as you would be violating your NDA otherwise) be sure and **also** send this info in the feedback app that is installed on all macOS beta's and placed in the dock. Apple needs to be notified of this issue at the very least.